# I am unsure how to entirely clear a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I believe I have gone through each element and eliminated it. I then set my head to to be empty at the end. However I am still getting a memory leak my test script. Any ideas on what to do to fix this?
 I have to write this function. I cannot use a destructor.

```
void LinkedList::Clear() {
    if (!head)
    {
        return;
    }

    LinkedListNode *pNode  = head;
    while(pNode )
    {
        head = pNode ->next
        delete pNode  ;
        pNode  = head ;
    }
    head = NULL ;
}
```

Comment: If this is for C++, you don't need to write a `Clear` method -- there's a destructor. You'll need to write that, though.

Comment: I suspect there is another allocation somewhere which is not getting recorded, because the only issue I can see with your script would be dependent upon race-conditions (i.e. threading)

Comment: Do you have a *working* function that deletes a single node?  If you do then don't duplicate code -- just call that function in a loop, deleting the head node, until the list is empty.

Comment: @erip - While it's true that you don't need it, it can be good to have it: "I have a LinkedList and I'd like to remove everything from it, then re-use it."

Comment: @iAdjunct Fair enough. Based on OP's use of `delete`, I doubt that's the case.

Comment: There does not appear to be a leak here. If you give us a complete example (or better still a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), we can find the leak.

Comment: @erip `If this is for C++, you don't need to write a Clear method` -- Tell that to the designers of ST:L (`std::list<T>::clear()`)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think you mean C++ standard library. `std::list<T>::clear` doesn't do what OP is trying to do.

Comment: @erip - note that `LinkedList` and `LinkedListNode` are two different things, so while he's `delete`ing the nodes, nothing said he's `delete`ing the `LinkedList`. However, he SHOULD provide a COMPLETE code example, showing the use of the list as well.

Comment: @erp *std::list<T>::clear doesn't do what OP is trying to do*  Sure looks like it to me: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/clear